# How to Build Hadoop 2.7.0 on Windows 8 64 bit?

Tags: java, windows, hadoop

I am unable to build Hadoop on my Windows 8 system. I keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (compile-ms-native-dll) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (compile-ms-native-dll) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed.
```

I have installed:

- Windows System
- JDK 1.8
- Maven 3.0 or later
- ProtocolBuffer 2.5.0
- CMake 3.2
- Windows SDK 7.1
- Internet connection for first build (to fetch all Maven and Hadoop dependencies)
- GnuWin32 and Git for instructions like sh and the likes...

From Building.txt:
"Unix command-line tools are also included with the Windows Git package which
can be downloaded from http://git-scm.com/download/win."

The version of Hadoop I am trying to install is 2.7.0... any help is appreciated

EDIT:

My PATH variable:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Parallels\Parallels T
>   ools\Applications;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Win
>   dows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\8.1\Wi ndows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsof t SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\P
>   ython27;C:\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Ant\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;c:\Program
>   F iles (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program File s
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Vi sual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft  SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C: \Program Files
>   (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\protobuf;C:\maven\bin;C:\Java\jdk\bin;C:\gnuwi
>   n32\bin;C:\hadoop\bin;C:\hadoop\sbin;C:\CMake\bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Frame
>   work64\v4.0.30319;C:\cygwin64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows
>   Performance Too lkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\bin

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build Hadoop after making a new Windows virtual machine and installing only the required prerequisites. I guess I had some messed up environment variables before.

EDIT:

You can find the generated files here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35333361/hadoop-2.7.0.7z

Comment: It will be good if you could share the native libraries for windows that got generated.